# How to change "such a thing" to "such things"?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, articles, adjectifs, pluriel

If you want to express the idea of "such things" (plural) in French, do you need to change "**une | a**" into "**de | some**", as shown in the following example?

> { I never wanted to get involved ... }
>
> « Je n'ai jamais voulu me retrouver impliqué ...
>
> 1A. dans une chose pareille. » { in such a thing | Singular }
>
> 1B. dans une pareille chose » { in such a thing | Singular }
>
> 2A. dans des choses pareilles » { in (some) such things | Plural }
>
> 2B. dans de pareilles choses » { in (some) such things | Plural }

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina et al: pour répondre à la question, merci de poster une réponse, pas un commentaire. Les commentaires sont susceptibles d'être effacés à tout moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All phrases are OK.

- 1A, 2A are the most common and are equivalent:

  > dans une chose pareille.
  >
  > dans des choses pareilles.
- 2B also exists, but is more stylish:

  > dans de pareilles choses.
- 1B is correct but rare:

  > dans une pareille chose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1A in plural becomes 2A, 1B in plural becomes 2B.
So yes, but you may want to put the adjective first, as shown in the Bs, to emphasize the description aspect.